# Remove rows from a data frame that contain duplicate information across the columns

Tags: r

```
col1 <- c('A','B','C', 'D')
col2 <- c('B','A','C', 'C')
col3 <- c('B','C','C', 'A')
dat <- data.frame(cbind(col1, col2, col3))
dat

  col1 col2 col3
1    A    B    B
2    B    A    C
3    C    C    C
4    D    C    A
```

I would like to remove rows 1 and 3 from dat as the letter B is present more than once in row 1 and the letter C is present more than once in row 3.

EDIT:

My actual data contains over 1 million rows and 14 columns, all of which contain character data. The solution that runs the fastest is preferred as I am using the dataframe in a live setting to make decisions, and the underlying data is changing every few minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try this (but I'm sure there is a better way)

```
cols <- ncol(dat)
indx <- apply(dat, 1, function(x) length(unique(x)) == cols)
dat[indx, ]
#   col1 col2 col3
# 2    B    A    C
# 4    D    C    A
```

Another way (if your columns are characters and if you don't have too many columns) is something like the following (which is vectorized)

```
indx <- with(dat, (col1 == col2) | (col1 == col3) | (col2 == col3))
dat[!indx, ]
#   col1 col2 col3
# 2    B    A    C
# 4    D    C    A
```

Comment: I have 14 character columns, which would mean I would have to check for 91 equivalencies. If I went through the trouble of listing each one (which I won't), would r be able to handle it and would it theoretically run faster than using the apply approach?

Comment: How big is your data? Did the `apply` approach took too much time to run?

Comment: I edited my original question to address your question about the size of the actual data I am working with. Using your `apply` solution worked in roughly 30 seconds. It may not be possible but I was hoping to get that number under 10 seconds.

Comment: @akrun I think it is less *memory* efficient, but more *time* efficient than `apply`, I think its not such a big deal benchmark, just don't have time for that right now.

Comment: @DavidArenburg  Thanks, I will try some benchmarks.

Comment: I wonder how long something like this runs `cols <- ncol(dat);
indx <- vapply(strsplit(do.call(paste, dat), " ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) length(unique(x)), integer(1)) == cols;
dat[indx, ]`

Answer (score 3):

You could do this in [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html), if you don't mind specifying the columns:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(repeats = max(table(c(col1, col2, col3))) - 1) %>%
  filter(repeats == 0) %>%
  select(-repeats) # if you don't want that column to appear in results


Source: local data frame [2 x 3]

  col1 col2 col3
1    B    A    C
2    D    C    A
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative.  I haven't tested on big dataset,

```
library(data.table) #devel version v1.9.5
dat[setDT(melt(as.matrix(dat)))[,uniqueN(value)==.N , Var1]$V1,]
#    col1 col2 col3
#2    B    A    C
#4    D    C    A
```

Or use `anyDuplicated`

```
 dat[!apply(dat, 1, anyDuplicated),]
 #   col1 col2 col3
 #2    B    A    C
 #4    D    C    A
```

Comment: I ran both lines of code you provided but got the following error - Error in is.data.table(x) : could not find function "melt"

Comment: @drumminactuary Sorry, I loaded the `library(reshape2)`

Comment: @drumminactuary you also need the development version of `data.table` for `uniqueN`, see [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: @akrun, you don't need `reshape2` with the dev version as far as I can remember from the README